# Sample points based on multiple conditions

Tags: qgis, point, sampling

Can anyone suggest a QGIS/R approach to sample from a polygon n points that satisfy some conditions depending on underlying raster layers values?

E.g. I have a country polygon and I would like to sample 10 points such that for those points the population density (density_raster) is >100 and altitude (altitude_raster) is <1000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS:

Use the [Raster Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html) to create a raster that is equal to 1 anywhere the `population density > 1000` condition is satisfied and where the altitude raster's condition (`< 1000`) is also satisfied.

[Polygonize](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/raster_to_vector.html) the output raster. Use a definition query on the result to only show the areas with a value of 1. This area is now a polygon representation of the areas where both of your conditions are satisfied.

Now use **Vector > Research Tool > Random Points Inside Polygons** with your intersected polygons and specify whatever other parameters you deem appropriate.